# What's the issue with following PHP MySQL code?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection

I'm using PHP and MySQL database.

```
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","XYZ","pqr") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
    mysql_select_db("LMN", $con); 

    //Code and SQL query to find out the User transactions count of all types from beginning till today's date
    $sql  =" SELECT COUNT(*) `carried out`, SUM(transaction_status = 'success') `success`, ";
    $sql .=" SUM(transaction_status = 'inprocess') `inprocess`, SUM(transaction_status = 'fail') `fail`, ";
    $sql .=" SUM(transaction_status = 'cancelled') `cancelled` FROM OCN.user_transaction ";



    $result = mysql_query($con,$sql);
echo $result; die;  

    $r =  mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

If I'm going to `echo $result` then blank screen appears. I'm not getting what's the wrong thing with this code? Can anyone help me in identifying the bug?

Comment: You're connecting using `mysql_*` and then running `mysqli_query` - they're mutually exclusive, and you can't mix them like that.

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Not to mention you're using `mysql_*`...otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: You're echoing a `mysqli_result` object.  Are you trying to echo the results of your query? Or the `$sql`?

Comment: I've made achange, mysqli is changed to mysql. But still the same result "Blank Page".

Comment: What are you expecting to be echo'd? You can't just simply echo a mysql_result.

Comment: @AaronW.: Yes I executed the same query in PHP MY Admin. It executes perfectly there. Even if I print the SQL query here it prints finely.

Comment: @phpLover - that's not the right syntax for `mysql_query()` - the connection is the second parameter, and is optional (it'll use the most recent connection if one isn't specified)

Comment: look at [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array)

Comment: @JasonMcCreary It's not future tense any more, `mysql_query` *is* [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) in [PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/releases/5_5_0.php) which was released in June.

Comment: Where do you echo your results? Also remove $con from mysql query

Comment: Can anyone provide me the proper answer please?

Comment: `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); $r = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC); print_r($r);`

Comment: @AaronW.:Your code really worked for me. Thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: Tip: create a new user for your code to connect to a database instead of using "root" and never post a password to any public forum especially "root".

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$r = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
print_r($r);
```